# How to format the background color of page footers and headers

Tags: formatting, stylesheet

I have created a StyleSheet by modifying a copy of Default.nb. The StyleSheet applies a dark grey background at the Notebook level. However, when I export to PDF and exam Print Preview (although PDF is the intended output), the page headers and footers show as large, white rectangles. I would like to change their color.

I have attempted to parse the code in the StyleSheet and identified references to headers and footers at the Notebook level and under the "Styles for Printed Runningheads and Footers" dropdown. However, I am a beginner to the language and have not found an explicit example. I have also looked at the "Headers and Footers..." menu under Print Settings. However, the background option in the GUI affects the color behind any text and not the entire page header/footer.

Any discussion is always appreciated. Thank you kindly in advance!